# How do I fix this issue: "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: [BABEL]"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dependencies, expo

> #node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: [BABEL]

I already installed all the dependencies for my project, and I'm getting this issue, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

#package.json - Main

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "my-project"
}
```

[image]

Comment: try deleting the ```node_modules``` folder and reinstall all the dependencies. with ```yarn add``` or ```npm install```

Comment: I did it but, is still giving me the same situation....

Comment: [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10964) _italic_ **bold** However, I updated the version of Babel, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: The problem was with dependencies that you installed, I corrected it and the app is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked your GitHub repo, as pointed out by `byCedric`, your Problem was with dependencies that you were using. I made the following changes and the app appears to be working,

Screenshot:

[image]

`package.json`

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.6",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

after installing all the dependencies mentioned above, I faced two more issues with the following files:

1. `node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js`
2. `node_modules\react-native-dotenv\index.js`

They were using `Node standard library module "fs"` , so I replaced it with `react-native-fs` package in both the above files.

both files after modifying:

```
//node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js

const fs = require("react-native-fs")
const path = require('path')

function log (message /*: string */) {
  console.log(`[dotenv][DEBUG] ${message}`)
}
...
```

```js
// node_modules\react-native-dotenv\index.js
const {readFileSync} = require("react-native-fs")
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

function parseDotenvFile(path, verbose = false) {
  let content
...
```

also there was a typo in the `WeatherDetails.js`, you passed `unitSystem` instead of `unitsSystem` as a `props`

Comment: Hi react-native-dotenv maintainer here. I highly recommend against using "react-native-fs". This is a common indicator that babel was misconfigured such that react-native-dotenv was set as a preset and not a plugin

Comment: Thank You Kemal for replying, and thanks for contributing to such a helpful open source library 

Answer (score 3):

Simply deleting `node_modules` and executing `npm install` as well as a `npx expo install` was enough to get my app up and running again.

Answer (score 2):

If you came here after updating to Expo SDK 50, you now need to install `babel-plugin-module-resolver` dependency manually:

```bash
npx expo install babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

You can take a look at related expo github issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/25923#issuecomment-1909002141

Answer (score 1):

Posting what worked for me as tears rolling down my cheeks......
update your npm and node version.
.
.
.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nvm-for-windows-how-to-download-and-install-node-version-manager-in-windows-10/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33552478)

Comment: Ya Sure!! ()
               . .

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why i had this error using yarn. So, I changed to npm install instead o yarn install.

`expo init my-project-name --npm`

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using `npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject --template`, I solved the issue by running `npm install` after creating the project.

Answer (score -2):

1. using NPM, npm install nativewind
2. using Yarn, yarn addd nativewind

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to fix the author's issue?